# Paging with PagedList

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pagination, pagedlist

This is my repository layer:

```
public List<Section> GetAllSections()
{
    return context.Sections.Include("Groups").Include("Groups.Classes").ToList();
}
```

This is my application layer:

```
public List<Section> GetAllSections()
{
    return cacheSectionRepo.GetAllSections();
}
```

And in controller I have:

```
SectionApplication sectionApp = new SectionApplication();
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(sectionApp.GetAllSections());
}
```

Now I want to make my `Index` view paged.I want to use from PagedList.How should I do this?
For example I want every page shows 5 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a page number and page size to the repository layer, and then use the `Skip` and `Take` Linq statements to filter out the rows you need:

```
public List<Section> GetAllSections(int pageSize=5, int pageNo)
{
    return cacheSectionRepo.GetAllSections().Skip(pageSize * pageNo).Take(pageSize);;
}
```

alternatively you could perform that filtering in you r repository layer. Then with every request to the controller, you would send the `pageNo` to the controller, preferably through an AJAX request.